# Using Selenium with NodeJS and the Brave browser (on MacOS Big Sur)

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, brave-browser

I'm trying to run some simple tests on a NodeJS app, using Selenium and the Brave browser.

I'm running Big Sur (11.5.2), using Brave version:

```
Version 1.28.105 Chromium: 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (x86_64)
```

I've downloaded the ChromeDriver, and I've installed in my path:

```
> which chromedriver
/Users/dd/bin/scripts/chromedriver

> chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107 (87a818b10553a07434ea9e2b6dccf3cbe7895134-refs/branch-heads/4515@{#1634})
```

I've created a folder, yarn inited, added the `selenium-webdriver` as a dev dependency,

```json
{
  "name": "seleniumtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "seleniumtest",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-beta.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./index.js"
  }
}
```

run up the following Javascript file, `index.js`:

```js
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('brave').build();
  try {
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

I've fired up the chromedriver:

```
> chromedriver          
Starting ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107 (87a818b10553a07434ea9e2b6dccf3cbe7895134-refs/branch-heads/4515@{#1634}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

but when I run `yarn start` I get :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Do not know how to build driver: browser; did you forget to call usingServer(url)?
```

If I replace `Builder().forBrowser('brave').build();` with `Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();` then Chrome fires up, but the window just sits there trying to load `data:,` in the url bar. I tried `chromium` - same result as for `brave`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setChromeBinaryPath function and point the brave binary path to it:

```
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');    
(async function helloSelenium(){
    let options = await new chrome.Options();
    options.setChromeBinaryPath('/opt/brave.com/brave/brave-browser');
```

in the forBrowser('brave') replace it with 'chrome', as selenium will do a switch case with that and only the values in Browser enum will be valid (chrome, edge, firefox, internet_explorer, safari, opera);